# Blazor cookies issue (Mark cross-site cookies as Secure to allow setting them in cross-site contexts)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, blazor

[SOLVED READ COMMENTS ]

I got a problem with the asp.net core hosted Blazor app.

locally it works like charm, when it is deployed there is a problem related to the cookies, that I don't know how to fix, I did my best, now seeking help :)

The problem is: once the user comes to the login page he gets this message in the console:

[image: View issues]

Here I found those cookies in response

[image: Cookie values]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to fix this issue in this scenario, I have tried everything, only one thing will work that is SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome version 80 or higher will block all third-party cookies by default. If you use the api using `HTTPS`, switch the protocol to the HTTPS and check whether the Set-Cookie in the response header contains SameSite=None and Secure.

If it doesn't use `HTTPS`, Chrome 80 will intercept the login function under the http protocol, causing the entire local deployment service to be unavailable. For this situation, open `chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies` and `chrome://flags/#cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure` in chrome, set it to be `Disabled`.

Comment: these flags do not exist in Chrome 119.0.6045.124